# Security rules for firestore and firebase storage - avoid external sign-up

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-storage

I'm developing a React Web App that uses a Firestore database to store some collections and Firebase storage for images. It's my first time using Firebase. It's time about time to go into production and I need to configure the security rules for the project.

I read Firebase's documentation and found out that the type of interactivity I want to allow to the app's users isn't considered secure (according to firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#all_authenticated_users))

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

(The above are the security rules for the Firestore database. Would apply the same for storage)

However, it seems this is exactly the behaviour I need in my app. Why? Let me explain...

I use email and password authentication from Firebase authentication. I want all my logged-in users to be able to read and write to the Firestore database and Firebase storage. There should be no differentiated roles, nor restricted access to the documents owned by the authenticated user. Restricting read and write to specific uid isn't an option either because all logged-in users should be able to sign up new users (via the createUserWithEmailAndPassword method).

I read a little bit more and found out this is insecure because someone could sign up for my project's Firebase authentication externally. It seems that I can solve this by restricting the domain where my API key can be used (as mentioned in [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#api_key_restrictions). This way users could only sign up from within the app.

Is this enough to prevent anyone from adding their credentials to the list of Firebase auth users and login to my app? Or should I implement further security measures?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read a little bit more and found out [that the `allow read, write: if request.auth != null;` rule] is insecure because
> someone could sign up for my project's Firebase authentication
> externally.

Yes it is "insecure" because as a soon as (1) someone has the apiKey of your Firebase Project and (2) the email/password sign-in method is enabled, this person can use the [Firebase Auth REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth) and sign-up to your project (i.e. create a new account).

Getting the apiKey is not very difficult if you deploy an app linked to your Firebase project (Android, iOS, Web...).

> It seems that I can solve this by restricting the domain where my API
> key can be used

AFAIK you cannot use an API Key to authenticate with the JS SDK (You could **maybe** generate a token based on the API Key and pass it to the `signInWithCustomToken()` method but I've never tried).

You could use the Firestore and Cloud Storage REST APIs and authenticate the users via the Auth REST API but doing so you'll loose all the advantages of the JS Client SDK, which is way simpler to use compare to the REST APIs.

On the other hand, a very common way to give access to only a set of users (for example, the employees of your company, or some paying subscribers to your app) is to use Custom Claims. You will find in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) the guidelines for setting access control with Claims.

---

Note that it is highly recommended not to use the `match /{document=**}` match statement but to have a specific match statement and corresponding rule for each (sub)collection of your DB. It may happen that one day you create a collection for which access should be restricted to a subset of your users: Having a specific match statement for each (sub)collection will force you to write a new match statement (and corresponding rule) for this collection.

Comment: I will check the custom claims option, and cheers for the tip on avoiding matching all documents. It's still unclear to me if restricting the API key to the domain of the app would effectively block any attempts to call sign-up/sign-in through the Auth REST API or would only limit read/write operations to the db/storage from outside my domain.

Comment: You may be interested by this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-admin-module-for-managing-users-access-and-roles-34a94cf31a6e) which presents how to build, with a Callable Cloud Function, a module for allowing end-users with a specific Admin role creating other users and how to restrict access to users with one or more specific Custom Claim(s).

Comment: yes! I just found out the time to do it recently. Took me a while, but learned a great deal about Firebase, emulators and claims along the way. Authentication is working as I intended by following a completely different approach to my first implementation :) Many thanks for the time to answer me and share the article you wrote.